# How to convert this javascript code in to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if (window.parent.frames['scripts1']) {
  if (window.parent.frames['scripts1'].document.documentElement) {
    var strSCRIPT = window.parent.frames['scripts1'].document.documentElement.textContent;
    if ((strSCRIPT.lastIndexOf('bbbbEND') - strSCRIPT.length) != -7) {
      window.parent.frames['scripts1'].document.location.href = 'test1.txt?refresh=' + Date();
    }
  } else {
    window.parent.frames['scripts1'].document.location.href = 'test1.txt?refresh=' + Date();
  }
}
```

I have tried lot of things but not success in writing something for cross browser.

Comment: if it works, why fix it?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: jQuery is a library built on Javascript. Your intention shouldn't be to change your javascript to jQuery, as jQuery ***is*** javascript. If you have no issues with this code, I see no valid reason of "converting" it to jQuery.

Comment: IIRC, crossing frames through JS isn't going to be supported on all browsers. This also seems like a very convoluted and probably slow way to refresh content...

Comment: Unless pedantry is intended, people need to consider before commenting that when a user asks about converting JavaScript to jQuery, they're *almost always* asking about converting DOM API to jQuery API. This usually isn't that hard to figure out.

Comment: @amnotiam although in this case there's no API usage as such, only DOM property accesses :)

Comment: @Alnitak: But those properties are part of the DOM API. *(And to be clear, I wasn't referring to your comment. Just that other answer, which is now a comment.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some jQuery conceptual material to get you started:

```
// make sure to give your frame an ID, and then it's easy to access
var frame_a = $( "#frame_a" );        

// jQuery's content() function seems to only work on iFrames, not on Frames
var frame_a_document = $( frame_a[0].contentDocument );        

var frame_a_document_body = frame_a_document.find( "body" );
var frame_a_text = $( frame_a_document_body ).text();        

alert( frame_a_text );
```

Keep in mind this important fact: Your frame is loaded after the parent document is finalized which means that the ready() function will be executed before the frame is loaded. If you try to access your frame in your ready() function, most likely you will get nothing because it's not been loaded yet -- i.e., it's race condition.

Answer (score 2):

First, refactor your code to eliminate repetition:

```
var s = window.parent.frames['scripts1'];
if (s) {
    var d = s.document;
    var e = d.documentElement;
    var t = e ? e.textContent : null;
    if (!t || t.length - t.lastIndexOf('bbbbEND') != 7) {
        d.location.href = 'test1.txt?refresh=' + Date();
    }
}
```

There's one identified compatibility issue but at least now we've got a chance of spotting it!

Specifically, `.textContent` isn't supported in IE8 or earlier, hence:

```
var s = window.parent.frames['scripts1'];
if (s) {
    var d = s.document;
    var e = d.documentElement;
    var t = e ? (e.textContent || e.innerText) : null;
    if (!t || t.length - t.lastIndexOf('bbbbEND') != 7) {
        d.location.href = 'test1.txt?refresh=' + Date();
    }
}
```

Comment: `.textContent` is not compatible with all commonly used browsers, but at least you've provided a positive reworking of the code.

Comment: @amnotiam hmm, maybe there is some scope for jQuery after all, then!  Ah, it's only IE8 and lower that doesn't support it.

Comment: Well, if this is the only compatibility patch needed, then I'd say jQuery would be massive overkill. I'd rather see a quickie `|| e.innerText` instead.  ...and yes, IE8 and lower would be the only issue. Unfortunately IE8 still has significant usage, though dwindling.

Comment: @amnotiam I reverted out your edited as I was in the middle of another one - I wanted to show the original code refactored, and _then_ show the cross browser fix.

Comment: .textContent works only for firfox and .innerText work for IE then what about other browser like chrome,safari etc

Comment: @Abhishek: All browsers except IE 8 and lower support `.textContent`. Not just Firefox.